# How to swap values of two AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-spinner, autocompletetextview

I have added two `autoCompleteTextView` with simple spinner and now I want to interchange their values by clicking an `Imageview`. But Whenever I click that `ImageView`, my app restarts. There is no error or warning.

 Here's the Java code **(UPDATED)** :-

```
public class location extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AutoCompleteTextView autoText1,autoText2,autoText3;
    private int selected,selected1;
   String[] locnames,locnames1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bus_route);

    locnames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Loc_names);
    locnames1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Loc_names);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            locnames);

    autoText1 =(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv1);
    autoText1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    autoText1.setThreshold(1);
    autoText1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //autoText1.showDropDown();
            hideKeyBoard(view);//move here
            //String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            selected = position;
             }
    });
    autoText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View arg0) {
            autoText3.setText(null);
            autoText1.showDropDown(); }
    });
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            locnames1);


    autoText2 =(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv2);
    autoText2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
    autoText2.setThreshold(1);
    autoText2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //autoText2.showDropDown();
            hideKeyBoard(view);//move here
           // String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
             selected1 = position;
            }
    });
    autoText2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View arg1) {
            autoText3.setText(null);
            autoText2.showDropDown(); }
    });


         final ImageView arrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow1);    
        arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View arg3)
            {

                autoText1.setText(locnames[selected1]);
            autoText1.clearFocus();
            autoText2.setText(locnames1[selected]);

            autoText2.clearFocus();
            int temp = selected1;
           selected1 = selected;
           selected = temp;


            //arrow.setRotation(arrow.getRotation() + 180);

            mCurrRotation %= 360;
            float fromRotation = mCurrRotation;
            float toRotation = mCurrRotation += 180;

            final RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(
                    fromRotation, toRotation, arrow.getWidth()/2, arrow.getHeight()/2);

            rotateAnim.setDuration(500);
            rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);

            arrow.startAnimation(rotateAnim);

            }

        });
    }
```

Also check that Rotation out, it has also no error but still nothing is happening. Thank you for your help.
**EDIT:**
 I have figured out the rotation. It can be done by

```
arrow.setRotation(arrow.getRotation() + 180);
```

or if want to animate then,            
First declare a variable
 `private int mCurrRotation = 0;`
then

```
            mCurrRotation %= 360;
            float fromRotation = mCurrRotation;
            float toRotation = mCurrRotation += 180;

            final RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(
                    fromRotation, toRotation, arrow.getWidth()/2, arrow.getHeight()/2);

            rotateAnim.setDuration(1000);
            rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);

            arrow.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
```

Comment: There must be some error if the app is crashing. Otherwise, your code might be handling the exception in a try/catch block somewhere.

Comment: if I remove these two lines, it works perfect. autoText1.setSelection(selected1);
autoText2.setSelection(selected);

Comment: Can you see the crash log in your logcat?

Comment: Remove any filters in logcat, you should be able to see the log

Comment: I'll check the logcat but it's the issue related with those two dropdowns as any first will pop up on click but the second one must pop up only on double click. I don't know why.

Comment: try removing `arrayAdapter1` and using same `arrayAdapter` for spinner no 2. It maybe the case that different positions are getting sent to spinners

Comment: Nothing has changed bro, still same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150617/discussion-between-lalit-singh-fauzdar-and-harshil-pansare).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no direct method available to set selection on AutoCompleteTextView, you need to access the array and set the text on AutoCompleteTextView.
Here is the solution.

```
public class StackOverflowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
AutoCompleteTextView actvFrom,actvTo;
ImageView ivSwap;
private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
        "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
};

int fromIndex,toIndex;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stackoverflow);
    actvFrom = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvFrom);
    actvTo = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvTo);
    ivSwap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivSwap);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> fromAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,COUNTRIES);
    ArrayAdapter<String> toAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,COUNTRIES);

    actvFrom.setAdapter(fromAdapter);
    actvFrom.setThreshold(1);
    actvTo.setAdapter(toAdapter);
    actvTo.setThreshold(1);


    actvFrom.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            fromIndex = position;
        }
    });
    actvFrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            actvFrom.showDropDown();
        }
    });
    actvTo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            toIndex = position;
        }
    });
    actvTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            actvTo.showDropDown();
        }
    });

    ivSwap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            actvFrom.setText(COUNTRIES[toIndex]);

            actvTo.setText(COUNTRIES[fromIndex]);

            int temp = toIndex;
            toIndex = fromIndex;
            fromIndex = temp;
            actvTo.clearFocus();
            actvFrom.clearFocus();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Surprising thing is your code 
actvFrom.setText(COUNTRIES[toIndex]);
actvTo.setText(COUNTRIES[fromIndex]);         is working but clicking that button causing the second spinner left open. I have to click again somewhere on the screen to hide it. Any solution?

Comment: Causing more issues. swaps only first time and last used spinner lefts open only once, after this nothing works on clicking

Comment: its working fine on my pc. no such issues encountered. update your code in question

Comment: Rechecked my code with yours and still on the first click, first spinner lefts open and after that works great. Don't know why?

Comment: remove showDropDown method from onItemSelected listener.

Comment: There's nothing like onItemSelected. And It is not in the onItemClick of any textview.

Comment: try removing hideKeyboard method

Comment: Thanks for your so much effort but It's still the same.